# Jmeter extraction and using on If Controller

Tags: json, api, jmeter, response

Is there's a way I can simulate this scenario, Example If there's a value extracted it will execute "TC1" Request, but If I extracted blank value it will execute "TC2".

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method which provides maximum flexibility is using [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)

As per documentation:

> If the switch value is out of range, it will run the zeroth element, which therefore acts as the default for the numeric case. **It also runs the zeroth element if the value is the empty string.**
>
> If the value is non-numeric (and non-empty), then the Switch Controller looks for the element with the same name (case is significant). **If none of the names match, then the element named "default" (case not significant) is selected**. If there is no default, then no element is selected, and the controller will not run anything.

So given the following [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) structure:

- Switch Controller, switch value - your extracted variable

  - [Simple Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller) with an arbitrary name

    - TC2 sampler(s) as child(ren) of the Switch Controller
  - Simple Controller with name `default`

    - TC1 sampler(s) as chidr(ren) of the Switch Controller

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)